# Nginx always return 502 using Homestead

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5, homestead

I`m using Laravel 5.2 with Homestead and I get this error on every request.

`/var/log/nginx/dev.me-error.log`

> 1415#1415: *1 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.10.1, server: dev.me, request: "POST /api/v1/auth/user/login HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "dev.me", referrer: "http://dev.me/"

This is nginx config, but it is reset on every provision, so I don't think that I can change it.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name dev.me;
    root "/home/vagrant/Code/public";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/dev.me-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/dev.me.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/dev.me.key;
}
```

**Update:**

I finally found the problem. It turns out that Nginx respond with 502 when validation error occurs.

This method is used for validating the data in the project:

```
public static function make()
    {
        if ( ! static::$rules) {
            throw new \Exception('Nothing to validate but expected to.');
        }

        $data = (self::$data ? self::$data : Request::all());

        $validator = parent::make($data, static::$rules, static::$messages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $messages = [];

            foreach ($validator->getMessageBag()->getMessages() as $field => $message) {

                $messages[$field] = array_pop($message);
            }

            throw new ValidationException($messages);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

The problem was `array_pop($message)` inside `foreach` that causes a php error (only in Laravel context):

`/var/log/php7.0-fpm.log`

> [31-Oct-2016 11:04:31] WARNING: [pool www] child 22235 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 1534.070207 seconds from start
>
> [31-Oct-2016 11:04:31] NOTICE: [pool www] child 22361 started

I could not find what this error means. I found similar errors only for old php versions.

The fix:

```
foreach ($validator->getMessageBag()->getMessages() as $field => $message) {

   $messages[$field] = $message[0];
}
```

I also tried to use `array_shift()` but it causes the same error as `array_pop()`.

If someone knows why is this happening, please tell me.

Comment: try to use TCP sock: `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;`

Comment: Now I got `500 hphp_invoke` with no error in the log.

Comment: Seems, this is a known [issue](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/new-cant-display-errors?page=1)

Comment: I have restarted Homestead with provision and it seems to be working but now again 502 on each request. Is there some cache or something?

Comment: Maybe this [thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/502-bad-gateway-nginx-197-in-homestead-laravel-5) can help?

Comment: I already have tried this with no success. :|